# Trying to copy and split data from single-row Google Form response into multiple rows on separate sheet only when necessary

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

FYI - I am completely new to this (as you will probably see from the code I've come up with), so apologies if this is a dumb question! I've searched around to try and solve the problem, but I've not been able to fix it yet and have no idea what I'm missing here.

Context: A non-profit has a Google Form as their client intake sheet. Clients can include up to 4 pets on their application, with a range of information provided for each animal. However, as each animal needs to be processed separately, the organization needs to have them listed in individual rows on the corresponding spreadsheet.

So far: I've come up with a function to copy the information from the original data sheet ("Data") to a separate sheet ("Responses") that the organization will access. I wasn't sure what to do to make things neat and tidy, so I just simply defined the "template" data (which is the owner information that would be copied to each required row) as well as the range for each animal that may or may not be filled out. The point is to check whether someone has filled out information for each additional animal, and then for each animal that has data, copy in a new row on the target sheet with the owner info and that animal's data.

Problem: In it's current form, it copies in 4 new rows every time, regardless of whether all 4 animal sets have data. For example, if one entry has data in the c1Values and c2Values, I still get 4 new rows in the target sheet. the first two are fully populated as they should be, and the 3rd and 4th rows have template data and then, naturally, empty cells in the animal info as there was nothing to copy. Can anyone see what I've done wrong in the code below? Any tips are appreciated!

Here's a copy of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phvG2cPo61qHEz3ptzTlIifEM1znV6hc_5wy4qZFudk/edit?usp=sharing

```
    function copyTo(destinationSSId) {
        // Open source SS at tab named "Data"
        let dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
        // Open destination SS at tab named "Responses"
        let responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Responses");;
        // Get source values
        let templateValues = dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 14).getValues();
        let c1Values = dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow(), 15, 1, 7).getValues();
        let c2Values = dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow(), 22, 1, 7).getValues();
        let c3Values = dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow(), 29, 1, 7).getValues();
        let c4Values = dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow(), 36, 1, 7).getValues();

        // Set first row
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 1, 14).setValues(templateValues);
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow(), 16, 1, 7).setValues(c1Values)

        // Set second row if applicable
        if (c2Values !==""){
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 1, 14).setValues(templateValues)
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow(), 16, 1, 7).setValues(c2Values)
        } 
        // Set third row if applicable
        if (c3Values !==""){
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 1, 14).setValues(templateValues)
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow(), 16, 1, 7).setValues(c3Values)
        }
        // Set fourth row if applicable 
        if (c4Values !==""){
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 1, 14).setValues(templateValues)
          responseSheet.getRange(responseSheet.getLastRow(), 16, 1, 7).setValues(c4Values)
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: My specific question is - how can I fix this so that it only copies in rows when needed? Currently, it copies all 4 rows every time, regardless of whether the set ranges of cells have data. So even if c3Values and c4Values are empty in the raw data sheet, my target sheet will end up with all 4 (and naturally, in the 3rd and 4th rows, the animal data is empty as there's nothing to copy in).

Comment: It looks to me that you just want to capture e.values and unshift the intake number onto the front and then post that complete array  to the bottom of the response sheet

Comment: I supposed I could be wrong perhaps you could explain what your trying to do with the data that you receive in the event object of a form submission trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Cooper. My trigger seems to be working fine; the function runs each time a new submission comes in. It's just the issue of my IF statements not working, and having unnecessary lines generated when there's no data (like a submission that should be made into two lines still getting made into four). Everything else is coming out as intended, in the right position on the target sheet. Just can't seem to make the conditional work so that it generates only as many new lines as necessary.

Comment: Yeah to be honest I didn't understand your code.  I would have done it with e.values and left the spreadsheet alone.  If you get multiple triggers quickly your code may not be able to figure out which execution goes with which line.  It's much better to use the onFormSubmit trigger and e.values[14] is the number of cats so that's how many lines you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the handler for your onFormSubmit trigger.

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rsh = ss.getSheetByName("Response");
  let rObj = { slidx: [{ start: 15, stop: 21 }, { start: 21, stop: 28 }, { start: 28, stop: 35 }, { start: 35, stop: 41 }] }
  let cus = e.values.slice(0, 14).unshift(['']);
  let o = [...new Array(e.values[13])].map((_, j) => {
    return [cus.concat(e.values.slice(rObj.slidx[j].start, rObj.slidx[j].stop))];
  });
  rsh.getRange(rsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```